# Double alignment with alignedat and a different line

Tags: align, alignment

I have a series of two equalities with the first one which is too long to fit a line, and the second which stays on a line. The first one should be splitted at half (there is a sum of terms between parentheses), so I thought of the environment `alignedat`. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
    A &= B + C + D + E &&(\alpha + \gamma + \delta + \epsilon\\
    & &&+\delta)\\
    &= B + C + D + E\alpha + E\gamma + \ldots
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output
[image]
I would like to forget the second alignment tab in the second line. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a top `aligned` for splitting the first equation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &= \begin{aligned}[t]
     B + C + D + E &(\alpha + \gamma + \delta + \epsilon\\
                   &+\delta)
     \end{aligned}
\\
  &= B + C + D + E\alpha + E\gamma + \dotsb
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow :) Perfect!